# Using ServiceLoader to get All Instances of an Annotation

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, modular, modular-design

All!

I know that long questions are frowned upon, but this is the only way I will be able to get my problem adequately explained. So, I apologize up front for the length of this question.

I am working on a modular project that will be extensible via add-on modules. To that end, I am wanting to allow add-on modules to be able to provide their own menus, menu items and toolbar buttons. To accomplish this, I have created an API with some annotations in it. This API is located in a module called "Menu.API", and has the following classes defined:

`@MenuProvider`:

```java
package com.my.menu.api;

@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.CLASS)
@Repeatable(RepeatableMenus.class)
public @interface MenuProvider {
    String name();
    String text();
    int position();
}
```

`@RepeatableMenus`:

```java
package com.my.menu.api;

@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface RepeatableMenus {
    MenuProvider[] value();
}
```

For the sake of brevity, we will only concentrate on this annotation, because I am sure the rest of them will work with whatever solution I am able to get for this one.

With this module completed, I created the `module-info.java` file with the following contents:

```java
module Menu.API {
    requires java.base;   // Just for the sake of completeness.

    exports com.my.menu.api;
}
```

So, with the API in place, I created a second module called "Menu.Platform", with the following class defined:

```java
package com.my.platform;

// Imports removed for brevity.

@MenuProvider(name = "fileMenu", text = "File", position = Integer.MIN_VALUE)
@MenuProvider(name = "editMenu", text = "Edit", position = Integer.MIN_VALUE + 1)
@MenuProvider(name = "toolsMenu", text = "Tools", position = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1000)
@MenuProvider(name = "helpMenu", text = "Help", position = Integer.MAX_VALUE)
public class App {

    private final MainFrame mainFrame;
    private final JMenuBar menuBar;
    private final JToolBar toolBar;
    private final JPanel statusPanel;
    private final JLabel statusLabel;
    
    public static MenuProvider provider() {
        // I am not sure how to send back my @MenuProvider annotations.
    }

    public App() {
        configureWindowParts();
    }

    private void configureWindowParts() {
        // No problems here...
    }

    private void initialize(String[] args) {
        // I do not need the args[] variable yet.
        
        createMenuBar();
    
        // ... the rest of the initialization.
    }

    private void createMenuBar() {
        ServiceLoader<MenuProvider> menusLoader = ServiceLoader.load(MenuProvider.class);

        // PostionableMenu is a subclass of JMenu that implements Comparable and provides
        //+ the `position` parameter.
        List<PositionableMenu> menus = new ArrayList<>();

        for (MenuProvider p : menusLoader) {
            PositionableMenu menu = new PositionableMenu(p.name(), p.text(), p.position());
            menus.add(menu);
        }

        Collections.sort(menus);

        menus.foreach(m -> {
            menuBar.add(m);
        });
    }
}
```

`module-info.java`:

```java
module Menu.Platform {
    requires java.desktop;
    requires Menu.API;

    uses com.my.menu.api.MenuProvider;
    uses com.my.menu.api.RepeatableMenus;

    export com.my.platform;

    provides com.my.menu.api.MenuProvider with com.my.platform.App;
}
```

So my problem is that I receive the error:

```
the service implementation type must be a subtype of the service interface type,
or have a public static no-args method named "provider" returning the service implementation
```

...when I do not have the `public static MenuProvider provider()` method in my `App` class. But then when I put that method in my `App` class, I have no clue how to return those four (4) `@MenuProvider`s from the method.

Any assistance that can be given to point me in the right direction is greatly appreciated. Thank you all in advance!

-SC

[EDIT]
Well, I spent so long thinking of just how to ask this question that the answer came to me shortly after posting it...

What needs to be returned from the `provider` method is obtained by reflecting on the class:

```java
    public static MenuProvider provider(){
        MenuProvider[] provider = App.class.getAnnotationsByType(MenuProvider.class);
        
        // How to return an array? If I change the return type to an
        //+ array, I get errors again because the provider method only
        //+ wants to return a single instance.
    }
```

This was my conundrum now. So I was thinking about how to edit this question when the answer hit me like a ton of bricks! Instead of returning the `MenuProvider`, I needed to return the `RepeatableMenus` instance.  The `value` property of `RepeatableMenus` returns an array of `MenuProvider`s. DUH!

So, I updated the `provider` method as follows:

```java
    public static RepeatableMenus provider(){
        RepeatableMenus provider = App.class.getAnnotation(RepeatableMenus.class);
        
        return provider;
    }
```

And, I changed my `module-info.java` file to this:

```java
module Menu.Platform {
    requires java.desktop;
    requires Menu.API;

    uses com.my.menu.api.MenuProvider;
    uses com.my.menu.api.RepeatableMenus;

    export com.my.platform;

    provides com.my.menu.api.RepeatableMenus with com.my.platform.App;
}
```

Now, I am receiving all of the `@MenuProvider` instances from my class. I cannot wait to try it from an additional module...

Thank you all anyway for the possible help you would have offered.

-SC

Comment: I think you should think though the entire use case first. There’s no point in having menu items automagically created, but no binding to an actual action to be performed when the item is selected. It makes far more sense to have *methods* being annotated, together with an interface implemented by the class declaring those methods. Then, use the service loader to find all implementations of the interface, followed by iterating over their methods, creating a menu item when the annotation is present, together with an action listener which will invoke the specific method.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! But I think that you may have missed something there. The `@MenuProvider` annotation that I am placing on the class is for a top-level or sub-menu. Those types of items do not have `Action`s associated with them, as they only display their contents. The annotations you are referring to are the next step. I already have an `@Action` annotation that creates a `javax.swing.Action` item that will be added to the `@MenuItemProvider`'s menu. In other words, I agree with what you are saying, just not in regards to the question posted. Thanks.

Comment: Since each class can have multiple `MenuProvider` annotations, the action annotations still have to somehow declare to which menu they belong, hence the `MenuProvider` annotation is redundant. Collect all actions and you know which menus have to exist.

Comment: @Holger, I actually do not believe that the `MenuProvider` is redundant because it allows third-party or late-added modules to provide their own top-level menu, if the one their action commands are to be in does not exist. As I have been working on this API, I have gotten rid of some redundancy, such as having to require a module's developer to have to use both the `MenuItemProvider` and the `ToolbarButtonProvider`. Therefore, I acted in a fashion similar to what you mentioned and changed `MenuItemProvider` to `ActionCommandProvider` to allow for a menu item and toolbar button to be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) explains quite well how it works with a good example.

First of all, it isn't designed to work with annotations. **The service loader is supposed to return all registered classes implementing a given interface**, not all classes marked with a given annotation.
Technically you can create classes that implements your annotation, but it's totally counter intuitive, and won't help you to find all marked classes.

Secondly, if your registered service implementation doesn't have a no-args constructor, or if it doesn't implement the service interface, it must have a static provider() method which returns an instance of the service interface.
It means that **you can only return a single instance** and not a list. If you want to have multiple services, you must have multiple classes.

If you want to find all classes marked with a given annotation as you have currently designed it, you will need to have a so called classpath scanner.
For example, [ClassGraph](https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph)

OF course if you are using a framework like Spring, you should use their discovery facility with their annotations like @Service or @Component, instead of reinventing the wheel. It is called context scan in that case.
Given your question, I assume you aren't using such a framework.